# How to print out several integer arguments in MARS, Using li $v0 1,syscall prints out only the first argument

Tags: assembly, mips, mars-simulator

I have this `main` function which calls another function `diffofsum` which do some calculation on those four arguments. When i use the `li $v0 1,syscall` it prints out only the first argument `2` in the Run/IO in MARS simulator. So the question is how can I print out all four arguments?.

```
.text
 main:

       addi $a0,$0,2    #argument 0 = 2
       addi $a1,$0,3    #argument 1 = 3
       addi $a2,$0,4    #argument 2 = 4
       addi $a3,$0,5    #argument 3 = 5
       jal  diffofsum       # call function 

       li $v0,1
       syscall
       add  $s0,$v0,$0  # return value

       li $v0,10
       syscall
```

Comment: Repeat for all numbers, possibly in a loop?

Answer (score 0):

That's because syscall prints the value stored in $a0, so you need to update $a0 to the values in $a1, $a2 and $a3.
Here's the long way of doing things:

```
li $v0,1
add $a0, $0, $a1
syscall #prints $a1

add $a0, $0, $a2
syscall #prints $a2


add $a0, $0, $a3
syscall #prints $a3
```

Of course, you can do this with a loop.